# How to make manual linking of PushNotificationIOS if there is no Libraries folder in Xcode project?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios, aws-pinpoint

How to make manual linking of PushNotificationIOS if there is no Libraries folder in Xcode project? Where should I put in this case?

Here is the structure of my project, I don't have Libraries folder there. [image]

I'm following this [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking) for manual linking.

That's expoKit project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this issue related to `ExpoKit` project, in expoKit project manual linking should be done differently than in pure react native project.

Here is example how to do it here is the first variant:

1.cd into your project and make sure you have a `podfile` (pod install)
2.You’re going to want to open up your finder then open up `project-name/ios/Pods/Headers/Public`
3.Your Xcode wants `React/RCTPush…` so drag and drop the React folder in 2. ^ into your header search path (since RCTPushNotificationManager.h is listed in here).
4. You can find your header search path by opening up `Xcode` and clicking on your project in the top left corner then opening up the Libraries folder and then opening up `RCTPushNotification.xcodeproj.`
5. Click `Build Setting` and type header search path in the search bar. Then open it up and drag and drop 3. ^ over.

Here is second variant:

in Podfile add the library which you need, in my case it was RCTPushNotification:

```
 pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTPushNotification"]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to doc :

> The most limiting thing about Expo is that you can't add in your own native modules without detaching and using ExpoKit. Continue reading the next question for a full explanation.

But expo project support push notification :

> Push notifications work right out of the box across both iOS and Android, using a single, unified API. You don't have to set up APNS and GCM/FCM or configure ZeroPush or anything like that. We think we've made this as easy as it can be right now.

see more [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/)

Comment: I'm using ExpoKit, not pure expo.